# Cant aply texture in x3dom object

Tags: html, object, textures, x3dom

i want to apply a texture in my x3dom objet in html, but when i aplly a texture the object turns black, can u guys help me?

Code

[image: code]

Image

[image]

Comment: Don't put code in screenshot, only in your post, please

Comment: Why do you not incorporate the changes people gave you before? c.f. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50936517/cant-fill-this-extruded-object

Did you check the console? I think it will tell you pretty much.